# How to Count Distinct with Group By and the entire Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a hard time wording what I need/wording the search result, so apologies if this is a stupid question/has been answered before. I'm trying to write a query in SQL for a table such as below:

```
Country    Unique_ID   
US         123
US         124
UK         125
Australia  126
```

That will output the follow table:

```
Country    Count_Distinct   
US         2
UK         1
Australia  1
All        4
```

I know I can select the countryid and count distinct the country codes, and I know I can just count distinct the countryid codes to get the "All" number. I can't figure out how to write a query to get the follow output that's not two separate queries.

If you need information or clarification please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: So if in your example, if the IDs for USA were 123 and 123, instead of 123 and 124, the "Count Distinct" would only be 1 instead of 2, right?

Comment: @kbball That's how I interpret it, but the column name `Unique_ID` suggests duplicates are not possible. Adding `distinct` to the count won't hurt, but it is more code noise...

Answer (score 4):

Use [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
select Country, count(distinct Unique_ID) Count_Distinct
from mytable
group by Country
with rollup
```

If you want the text "All" (you get a `null` for the country by default), wrap it in another query to change the null to "All":

```
select coalesce(Country, "All") Country, Count_Distinct
from (
    select Country, count(distinct Unique_ID) Count_Distinct
    from mytable
    group by Country
    with rollup
) x
```

Comment: You are missing the AS before Count_Distinct

Comment: @kbball "AS" is optional. I prefer less noise.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this :

select country,count(distinct unique_id) as count distinct 
from table
group by rollup(country)